# increasing overall "size" of .pdb file for gromacs simulation

Tags: pdb-files

I am attempting to create a simulation using gromacs based off of POPC128a.pdb and topol11885.top files that has 4 times the number of POP and Sol while maintaining all the other physical properties. Essentially, creating a POPC512a.pdb and topol47540.top to create a simulation. I know how to use editconf for the box size and a few other features, but I am new to gromacs and have looked through the documentation on how to possibly do this using editconf and other tools, but could not find a clear answer. Is there a simple way to make these changes? Or would I need to make these .pdb and .top files from scratch?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

The tag "pdb-files" refers to "Program Database" files which are not related at all to the software gromacs and the world of bioinfromatics. Researchgate website might be more suitable.

You might want consult the [gromacs resource/tutorial](http://www.gromacs.org/Documentation/Tutorials) webpage which plenty of useful links.

Answer (score 0):

You might replicate your simulation system coordinates with gmx genconf, and edit the topology file directly to specify the changed composition.